# property binding error when pipes is used

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, angular

i am following this tutorial

```
https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/angular-pipes-custom-pipes
```

and i am trying to get the code posted below working. when i invoke the command

```
ng servr --open
```

i get the following error:

```
Error occurs in the template of component Appcomponent
ptoperty file does not exist on type Appcomponent
```

please let me know why i am getting this error and how to fix it

**app.component.ts**:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core'
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
    file = { name: 'logo.svg', size: 2120109, type: 'image/svg' };
}
```

**app.component.html**:

{{file.name}}

{{file.size | filesize}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For using pipe we need to pass it in provider**

I have created [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9bk71w?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts) demo you can check, it is working fine in my case I have attached here so you can check.

let me know if you still face any issue will help you.

```
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9bk71w?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts
```

[image]

Comment: would you pls tell me what exactly i should add to the file to get it running?because most of your imports are underlined with red

Comment: First of all you need to create a pipe. After that  go to app.module.ts and add provider as i have added in the above screenshot. Now you can use that pipe with selector in HTML. I have added stackblitz demo where all file is there you can check. Please visit that link.

Comment: Can you please share your code or can you please create a stackblitz demo so I can idea?

Answer (score 1):

you have spell mistake in import
import { Component } from '@angulat/core'

change to

import { Component } from '@angular/core'

Answer (score 0):

The error says

> property file does not exist on type **Appcomponent**

Note its **AppComponent**... You have declared `FileComponent`

```typescript
export class FileComponent {
    file = { name: 'logo.svg', size: 2120109, type: 'image/svg' };
}
```

Simply you are using property `file` from `FileComponent` in `Appcomponent`

Comment: i changed it but still does not work and i receive this error Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.